# How to run a Tensorflow lite model in Windows with GPU in python

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I'm currecntly working with a Tensorflow lite model for Segmentation from here:  https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/segmentation/overview?hl=es-419 (deeplabV3)
and now that i started with the real-time video test, the model runs extremelly slow and i was wondering if it's possible to run the model in an Nvidia GPU or if there is any GPU delegate in python for Windows or if it's any alternative to use instead. Thanks